# WPF Grid Column width in DataTemplate does not work

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, catel

I have `DataWindow` and `UserControls` (different `ViewModels`).

**My `DataWindow.Xaml`:**

```
<catel:DataWindow.Resources>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MessageViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Views:MessageView Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</catel:DataWindow.Resources>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
```

**My `UserControl`: `MessageView.Xaml`**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
    </Border>

    <Border Grid.Row="1">
        ...
        Content
        ...
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

`Messages` : `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();`

My content in `UserControl` adds to `DataWindow` dynamically at runtime. If content width in `UserControl` is more than WindowWidth ColumnWidth (column1 20* and column2 80*) does not work. I see only Grid.Column(80*) and it's width is 100*. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you sure that your `Views:MessageView` knows about the parent `Grid` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914005/binding-grid-column-width-inside-usercontrol-to-parent-grid-column-width ?

Comment: Thanks for help! Problem is 
"It's impossible render an element 80% of windows when its size is more than windows size"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible render an element 80% of windows when its size is more than windows size.
for solving this problem you can make windows size dynamic by removing Windows Width attribute in your code.

Comment: Thanks! Can I Rerender window after View add? And if I rerender window - it be 20 and 80?

Comment: yes, when you use WPF bindings , by changing ViewModel rerender itself again if your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged and your list Must be ObservableCollection.